# .NET HTTP Client response exception

Tags: .net, http, exception, response

my main issue is that I am unable to properly get large amount's of data.

For example I am making an API call to basically get 10000 rows (800mb) of data as a response (A huge list) If I lower i take 100 rows(10mb of data) ~ it works, the database is old and blobs are saved inside, that's why it's so big. But with larger size I get an error:

Error while copying content to stream... (inner exception the response ended prematurely)

After a lot of digging I found that using parameter HttpCompletionOption in the request like this:

`response = await HTTPHelper.Client.SendAsync(req,HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);`

allows the response to work, but this just pushed error to the next line which is:

`var responseData = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<List<InspForm>>();`

Any help would be appreciated, because this makes no sense :/

Adding trace (after using HttpCompletionOption)

```
This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.FillAsync(bool)
    System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ChunkedEncodingReadStream.ReadAsyncCore(System.Memory<byte>, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
    System.Text.Json.Serialization.ReadBufferState.ReadFromStreamAsync(System.IO.Stream, System.Threading.CancellationToken, bool)
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable<TResult>.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
    System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadFromStreamAsync<TValue>(System.IO.Stream, System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
    System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.Result.get()
    System.Net.Http.Json.HttpContentJsonExtensions.ReadFromJsonAsyncCore<T>(System.Net.Http.HttpContent, System.Text.Encoding, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
    SyncClient.Form1.btnSync_Click(object, System.EventArgs) in Form1.cs
```

**Edit**

Response:

> StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
> {
> Date: Fri, 18 Nov 2022 13:47:03 GMT
> Server: Kestrel
> Transfer-Encoding: chunked
> Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
> }

Comment: What kind of exception it raises? Put it in a try...catch block. It might be any thing from deserialization errors to insufficient memory

Comment: @MDZand I added more of the exception to the original question.

Comment: I suggest writing the response to a file using a fileStream and check if the response is complete. So we can see if the format is correct and the problem is at the client side.

Comment: Either the server or the client has a bug, more (chunks of) data is expected in the response but not found. Create a [mre].

Comment: @MDZand I wrote to file I can't share it since it contains information that is private, but it's there almost 600mb in size of txt file with the values, although it might be cut off at the end. But here is a sample [{"key":"0001CCE07B3E4FE997C769C7EB00E23E","infoRef":"8887F29E7AF44FBCAD39E2290C5AC7D3","map":null,"created":"08/23/2022 08:59:06","modified":"08/23/2022 14:58:30","createdBy":"J LastName","modifiedBy":"M LastName","sync":"08/23/2022 14:58:31","deleted":false,"projectRef":"75073687188D4837B9D72A36E7E5F0A4"}

Comment: @MDZand it might cut off at the end. Map is byte array, and at the end it might be cut off, since it end's with the map without other features.

Comment: @CodeCaster I would do that, but I would need to share the database, which I can't since it does not work on small databases if I get only 100 records the same exact code works. It's either an issue in size of response time of the response or database value.

Comment: You can of course just generate fakes for those 100,000 records in an ASP.NET Core app, shouldn't take more than a few dozen lines of code. According to the exception, the server doesn't send a properly chunked response.

Comment: @CodeCaster I do realize that, but thing is this code that I am using does not return error if for example I take all columns except map (Map is blob (byte array), that makes up almost the entire size of the database without map the database is around 4MB instead of 700MB. In order to reproduce the error I have to include map.

Comment: @CodeCaster this is definitely an error that is either related to size or the response time, or the blob itself being corrupted maybe ? Not sure which one is the issue.

Comment: It's no use guessing. We don't have your database nor your code. Data itself is very unlikely to break .NET's implementation of HTTP. You can trivially create a representation of one or a few records in code, then have your server multiply those records in a fake response. Then keep incrementing the size until it reproduces the error.

Comment: ... but if writing the file works, the problem lies somewhere between reading the response and deserializing it from JSON and the interaction between those. Still, you're going to need a repro.

Comment: @CodeCaster is right! There are still some possibilities, from exceeding some limits to blob content characters breaking the deserialization. Maybe you can think out of the box: If possible just get headers (i.e. without map column) first and then get maps one by one or in chunks.

Comment: @CodeCaster I managed to move past the error apparently my odbc database was 32 bit, and after changing it to 64 bit it works. It's whole other issue for me, but this time the original issue is solved. I can't upgrade that old database to 64... I guess I will have to stick to old solution then. Or upgrade to 64bit overtime.

Comment: Ah so it would appear some part of the process runs out of available memory and dies, tearing down the connection with it. Nice find.